# How can vb.net append text to the same text file in multiple threads?

Tags: vb.net

I am writing a function for log output, but when this function is called in multiple places, an error will be prompted: thread occupation. How should I solve it?

the error：

```
IOException: The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\Administrator\source\repos\NSC 6\NSC 6\bin\Debug\net6.0-windows\log\log-latest.log' because it is being used by another process.
```

This is the code of the function

```
Function log_record(logtext As String)
    File.AppendAllText(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location) & "\log\log-latest.log", "「" & Now & "」" & logtext)
End Function
```

or

```
Function log_record(logtext As String)
    Dim log_writer As New StreamWriter(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location) & "\log\log-latest.log", True)
    log_writer.WriteLine("「" & Now & "」" & logtext)
    log_writer.Close()
End Function
```

Comment: Use the [SyncLock statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/synclock-statement) to ensure only one thread can write to the file at the same time.

Comment: I suggest you use nlog https://nlog-project.org/documentation/v4.6.0/html/T_NLog_Targets_Wrappers_AsyncTargetWrapper.htm